# ASP.NET Change Layout based on URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am still really new to ASP.NET so bear with me.

What I am trying to do is render a different layout based on the URL. So if it contains "Homeowner" it should display the HomeOwner layout. If it doesn't it should display the default shared layout.

Currently my attempt is cause it to redirect too many times when going to the HomeOwner route.

in the ViewStart.cshtml (Url in bar when this happens is "http://localhost:33486/HomeOwner?zipCode=12208"

```
@{
    if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString().Contains("HomeOwner"))
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/HomeOwner/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    } else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

}
```

Is there a better approach to achieve the result I want? Most of my application will use the shared layout, it is only HomeOwner views that will not.

Comment: You can use `Areas` for that purpose: https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mvc/controllers/areas.html. Each area is like a mini-MVC where you can have its own layout.

Comment: If it wasn't a full fledged application already that I am just modifying I would try that. But I think that would require a ton of reworking. Has to be a way to do it with just the Views, I would think? I've also tried just adding a _ViewStart.cshtml to the root of the HomeOwner view folder with the correct layout and I am still getting constant redirects.

Comment: In that case I would probably just add to shared layout if(!HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString().Contains("HomeOwner")){.shared layout html..}else{..homeowner layout here.}